# Number of times to roll a dice to get 4 or 2

Tags: probability

How many times do we need to roll a dice until 4 or 2 turns up?

I guess the probability for each is $1/6$. Since we have a "or" I guess it is $1/6+1/6$ and $4/6$ unwanted numbers. But I don't know how to compute the number of times we need to roll.

Comment: If you're lucky, you may roll forever :)

Comment: @peter.petrov That's the thing I dont think it is possible since we can get only 1. Is it possible that the question it self is wrong?

Comment: I think the question means: what is the expected number of times you need to roll the dice to get either 2 or 4? http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/LengthToFirstSuccess.shtml

Comment: @peter.petrov Well it doesn't say anything about expected...

Comment: You may be looking for the mean number of times. The probability of "success" on any roll is $\frac{1}{3}$. The number of rolls until the first success has geometric distribution, parameter $p=\frac{1}{3}$. The probability you need to roll $k$ times is $p(1-p)^{k-1}$. The mean iis $\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: @Erik I guess expected is assumed here. I don't see what other meaning this question could have other than that.

Answer (score 3):

Your success event is: we have 2 or 4.
The probability of this event (as you noted) is: 
$p = 2/6 = 1/3$.

So the expected number of times to perform the experiment
in order to get your first success is: $1/p = 1/(1/3) = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes 2/6 or 1/3 represents that on a given roll, it ends up being a 4 or a 2.

Theoretically, there is a chance that you may have to roll $99999^{99999}$ times until you get a 4 or a 2 for the first time, or it could happen on your first roll. What I think you are looking for, is that given you have $n$ rolls, what the chance that by the nth roll you will get a 2 or a 4.

Note: chance of not getting 2 or 4, as you pointed out, is: $4/6$

Assume you don't a 2 or a 4 on your first roll (this will 4/6 times). Then it may happen again that on you second roll, you still don't get a 2 or a 4. This will occur 4/6 out of the times on the second roll.

So the chance that you don't roll a 4 or a 6 on your first roll, and then fail again on your second row is: $(4/6)*(4/6)$

Clearly, the chance that you succeed is $1 - P($failure$)$ so: $1-(4/6)*(4/6)$

As you can work out, in general, the chance that you will roll a 4 or a 2 by your nth role (succeed) is:

$1-(2/3)^n$

The probability exponentially approaches 1, which makes intuitive sense, as getting no 4s or 2s after something like 50 rolls is extremely low, just as the formula suggests.

Answer (score 1):

For any number of rolls, we can't be sure that a 4 or a 2 shows up. Namely, we still have cases without a 4 or a 2, e.g. only ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable $X\sim Ber(\frac{1}{2},n)$ that says the number of successes after $n$ rolls.

$\mu = \frac{n}{3} \ \ \ \sigma =\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{2}{3}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{9n}}$

We want to be somehow sure of $X\geq 1$. We should begin but what is for you *sure enough*, but let's use for that $95\%$, which is usually used.

From that, it follows:

$P(X\geq 1)\sim P(Z\geq \frac{1-\mu}{\sigma})=P(Z\geq \frac{(2-n)\sqrt{2n}}{2})$

If we want to be $95\%$ sure, we are looking when $Z\geq -1.645$ ($Z$ follows a normal distribution)

All together:

$\frac{(2-n)\sqrt{2n}}{2}=-1,645\\
n\approx 3.2838$

So, with 3 rolls, you can't be yet $95\%$ sure. For that level of certainty you'd need 4 rolls.